# ServiceStack ORMLite SqlServer Post error on Dates

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

New to ServiceStack and trying to work through some examples of JSon client and SqlServer db. I have DTO object like this:

```
    public class InspectionResults : IHasIntId
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Alias("OID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int InspectorID { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

When I populate properties and try to post I receive Sqlerrors with Overflow on Date. Here is my Populate and Post. All data in properties appears ok.

```
 var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:50238/InspectionResults?");
        var res = client.Post( new InspectionResults
        {
            Active = inspection.Active,
            AssignedDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3),
            ChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            Description = inspection.Description,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now,
            Frequency = inspection.Frequency,
            InspectorID = 2,
            Instructions = inspection.Instructions,
            LocationID = inspection.LocationID,
            Notes = "These are my dummy notes for the whole Inspection",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-55),
            Title = inspection.Title
         });
```

Below is Response Body

```
{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"SqlTypeException","Message":"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.","StackTrace":"[InspectionResultsRequest: 6/11/2014 4:22:48 AM]:\n[REQUEST: {Id:0,Title:Clean Bathrooms,Description:First Floor Mens & Ladies Rooms,Instructions:Clean them Good,Frequency:\"\",Active:True,ChangedDate:2014-06-11T00:22:47.9550000-04:00,CreatedDate:2014-06-11T00:22:47.9550000-04:00,LocationID:1,AssignedDate:2014-06-10T21:22:47.9550000-04:00,StartDate:2014-06-10T23:27:47.9550000-04:00,EndDate:2014-06-11T00:22:47.9550000-04:00,InspectorID:2,Notes:These are my dummy notes for the whole Inspection}]\nSystem.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExtensions.LongScalar(IDbCommand dbCmd)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExecLongScalar(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.InsertAndGetLastInsertId[T](IDbCommand dbCmd)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.Insert[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj, Boolean selectIdentity)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22`1.<Insert>b__21(IDbCommand dbCmd)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.Insert[T](IDbConnection dbConn, T obj, Boolean selectIdentity)\r\n   at InspectorService.DataWorker.InspectionResultsDataWorker.AddInspectionResults(InspectionResults i) in c:\\Temp\\InspectorService\\InspectorService\\DataWorker\\InspectionResultsDataWorker.cs:line 27\r\n   at InspectorService.InspectionResultsService.Post(InspectionResultsRequest request) in c:\\Temp\\InspectorService\\InspectorService\\Services\\InspectionResultsService.cs:line 38","Errors":[]}}
```

Thank you for any direction.

added DataWorkerClass:

```
public class InspectionResultsDataWorker
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// A helper class that uses the ServiceStack.OrmLite Object Relational Mapper
    /// to support CRUD operations on the InspectionResults table.
    /// </summary> 
    // The IDbConnection passed in from the IOC container on the service
    System.Data.IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    // Store the database connection passed in
    public InspectionResultsDataWorker(System.Data.IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    // Inserts a new row into the InspectionResults table
    public int AddInspectionResults(InspectionResults i)
    {
        return (int)_dbConnection.Insert<InspectionResults>(i, selectIdentity: true);
    }

    // Return a list of InspectionResultss from our DB
    // (this is the equivilent of “SELECT * FROM InspectionResults”)
    public List<InspectionResults> GetInspectionResultsList()
    {
        var inspectionResults = _dbConnection.Select<InspectionResults>();
        var inspectionResultsItems = _dbConnection.Select<InspectionResultsItem>();
        List<InspectionResults> returnList = new List<InspectionResults>();

        foreach (InspectionResults ins in inspectionResults)
        {
            List<InspectionResultsItem> inspItemList = _dbConnection.Select<InspectionResultsItem>(q => q.InspectionResultsID == ins.Id);
    //        ins.InspectionResultsItems = inspItemList;
            returnList.Add(ins);

        }
        return returnList;
    }

    // Return a single InspectionResults given its ID
    public InspectionResults GetInspectionResultsByID(int id)
    {
        return _dbConnection.SingleById<InspectionResults>(id);
    }

    // Updates a row in the InspectionResults table. Note that this call updates
    // all fields, in order to update only certain fields using OrmLite,
    // use an anonymous type like the below line, which would only
    // update the Title and Description fields:
    // _dbConnection.Update(new { Title = “Inspect Tractors”, Description = “Check all Aspects of Tractor Operation” });
    public InspectionResults UpdateInspectionResults(InspectionResults i)
    {
        _dbConnection.Update<InspectionResults>(i);
        return i;
    }

    // Deletes a row from the InspectionResults table
    public int DeleteInspectionResultsByID(int id)
    {
        return _dbConnection.Delete(id);
    }

}
```

added Service Post and Add methods:
         // Creates a new InspectionResults
         public int Post(InspectionResultsRequest request)
         {
            var p = new InspectionResults()
            {

```
        };

        InspectionResultsDataWorker pdp = new InspectionResultsDataWorker(Db);
        return pdp.AddInspectionResults(p);
    }

 // Inserts a new row into the InspectionResults table
    public int AddInspectionResults(InspectionResults i)
    {
        return (int)_dbConnection.Insert<InspectionResults>(i, selectIdentity: true);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your OrmLite data access code? Usually people see this error when you use the c# default date which is not valid for SQL Server.

Comment: @kampsj thanks for reply, I edited question to add my worker class and Services Post. The InspectionResultsRequest Class is defined same way the DTO above is defined, only difference is class name and Routes of:   [Route("/InspectionResults", Verbs = "POST")]
    [Route("/InspectionResults/InspectionResultsID", Verbs = "PUT")]

Comment: Put breakpoint in your post method and verify values of your DateTime properties. Your DateTimes are not nullable so they get the default date 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM and when you try to save this value in database you get exception. If you checked it and I have right, then you have problem with date format when you send data to your post method.

Comment: @Adam thanks your comment sent me to the right place to look to find my rookie mistake. Embarrased to say, I was checking the client payload just prior to post, when I went to my Post Method in the service I found a stub of code that was creating a empty object from my Request payload thereby causing DTO to insert a new empty object. Thanks for the kick in the right direction.